# Progam for insertion sort in C,it is not comparing the unsorted element to all of the previous sorted elements

Tags: c

So I made this program using only `for` loops. I was just trying to see what would happen if I use `for` instead of `while` but the loop is only working for comparison between one sorted and unsorted element not the sorted elements before it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void insertion(int arr[], int y) {
    int h, z, temp, x;
    for (z = 1; z <= y; z++) {
        for (x = z - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
            if (arr[x] >= arr[z]) {
                temp = arr[z];
                arr[z] = arr[x];
                arr[x] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (h = 0; h < y; h++) {
        printf("\n %d", arr[h]);
    }
}

void main() {
    int arr[50];
    int x;
    printf("Enter the numbers of elemnts");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter the elements");
    for (int z = 0; z < x; z++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[z]);
    insertion(arr, x);
}
```

Comment: sorry but I am new to programming so correct me if i am wrong but theoretically i would be comparing the 1st unsorted element with the previous already sorted elements.Why would then for loop not work in this case ,i am not able to catch the mistake so if you can help with that,gesture would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) What you're asking is unclear in your question as it is. I suggest maybe adding what you're asking in your comment to your question, since a lot of people glaze over the comments and may not catch what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some off-by-1 errors and comparing to the wrong element (compared to:

```
i ← 1
while i < length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
    i ← i + 1
end while
```

from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm)

Try the following:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void insertion (int arr[],int y)
{
    int h,z,temp,x;
    for(z = 1; z < y; z++)
    {
        for(x=z; x > 0 && arr[x-1] > arr[x]; x--)
        {
            temp=arr[x];
            arr[x]=arr[x-1];
            arr[x-1]=temp;
        }
    }
    for(h=0;h<y;h++)
    {
        printf("\n %d",arr[h]);
    }
}
void main()
{
    int arr[50];
    int x;
    printf("Enter the numbers of elemnts: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Enter the elements\n");
    for(int z=0;z<x;z++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[z]);
    insertion(arr,x);
}
```

Comment: really appreciate the help.Thanks!